# How to save a local file programmatically given an amount of data and a file name with html5

Tags: html

I want to implement this use case found on the W3C File API document:

- User agents should provide the ability to save a local file programmatically given an amount of data and a file name.

  - Example: A Spreadsheet App. User interacts with a form, and generates some input. The form then generates a CSV (Comma Separated Variables) output for the user to import into a spreadsheet, and uses "Save...". The generated output can also be directly integrated into a web-based spreadsheet, and uploaded asynchronously.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#requirements

From my understanding, it should be possible to create a completely offline Spreadsheet app with this, but I could not find a single example both in the W3C document or on the web that has this kind of use case implemented. At least not a completely offline one. Of course it doesn't need to be a spreadsheet application; a simple text editor or TODO manager would suffice. Am I missing something?

Also, would this make it possible to create one of the previously mentioned applications (text editor, todo manager or even spreadsheet app) from a single html5 file (with embedded JS and css)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems I didn't search hard enough, here's an example of what I want http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

Comment: It seems that this demo does not work in a chrome version 25.
Console Error:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Newer demo:http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side